Show notification count which are visible on the notification tray on my app's icon in flutter
I want to show count of notifications received which are visible on the notification tray on my flutter app's launcher icon.
  FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((message) {
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      _handleNotification(message, 'na');
    } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
      _handleNotificationIos(message, 'na');
    }
  });
  FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((message) {
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      _handleNotification(message, 'click');
    } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
      _handleNotificationIos(message, 'click');
    }
  });

I am receiving notifications through the above code and also was able to see notification count on app launcher icon when app is closed. But recently i observed that it has stopped showing the count.
I want to achieve this :-
enter image description here
